# How long does it take to get Canadian Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas, work, vfs-global

Im sure this question has been touched on before however my situation is slightly unique which I belief warrants the opening of a new question, without being duplicate.

I have to apply for a Canadian Visitor Visa (Less Than 6-Month) AKA Tourist Visa.

**I want to be in Canada by 15 September** at the latest. I have already purchased my plane ticket which will have me leaving my country of residence on 14 September and arrive in Canada on 15 September

**Tomorrow is 10 August** and I will submit all my documents first thing in the morning. T*hus, leaving me with 35-Days to get my visa processed before my flight departs.*

According to Canada Visa Application Time Frame Calculator it says the folllowing:

[image]

QUESTIONS:

1. According to the above information I would love to get feedback from anyone who has gone through the Canadian tourist visa appllication in the past (I realize each case is unique), however talking averages, **how long did you wait?**, did you experience any delays for simple reasons, if yes what caused delays etc?
2. I have highlighted in the image above the statement `Does not include transit time between the VAC and IRCC office` I have googled the statement but could not find a definet answer. All I got was *this could add an extra 10-days to the application* which can possibly bring total time to 35 days (to long) ...considering I literally live next to the local Canadian VAC will this still be applicable to me / will it help me speed up process since Im close to the Canadian VAC and dont have to post anything...
3. If I submit application online instead of going through the Canadian VFS centre, can this help speed up the process slightly?
4. Considering the above info would an experienced traveler say I am doomed or may I just be lucky and get the VISA in time before my flight on 14-Spetember?

Any help / advice much appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

As I understand it the 6-months Visa allows you to go for business / studying and or / tourism...Not that I am planning to do any work or business, just curious if this is indeed the case...?

[image]

Comment: How can a capitalized "MUST be in Canada by such-and-such date" apply to a tourist trip?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because I need to meet someone for a trip looong story....can explain if you want details.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you are wrong though, since the 6-month entry visa allows you to Visit / Conduct Business / Study / Work Temporarily for a period less than 6-monts. Not that I am planning to do any business its my holiday, just correcting what I think is a wrong statement...but then again you probably know better. Would ll be interesting to get your input on this. Thanks

Comment: Just to point out something you must have overlooked. If you absolutely have to meet someone on 15 September, you will  apply regardless of the answer you get here making most of your question moot. As NIKE says, _just do it_.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomieأبوعمار Thanks for that -- however its A LOT of effort and paperwork (and stress), if I can get somewhat of an answer here at least it will give me some peace of mind and a bit of clarity. But you are right I am proceeding regardless. Will just be interesting to know some of the answers to questions aswell

Comment: IMO "Will I get my visa on time" is borderline opinion based. Perhaps you should consider rewording your question so that the answer does not deal in guesses.

Comment: @RedBaron DONE!

Comment: It took me more than a month. Applied in London.